How can I load many audio files in short time? (with Flutter Audioplayers)
I'd like to build a virtual instrumental with flutter.
So I have to load many assets(audio) files.
PROBLEM : It takes too much time to load assets
I'd like to reduce 'asset loading time' less than 10s.
I tried to load them sequentially. It worked, but took too much time.
  Future<void> _loadData() async {
    for (var note in notes){
      AudioPlayer player = AudioPlayer();
      player.setPlayerMode(PlayerMode.lowLatency);
      await player.setSource(AssetSource(note));
      player.resume();
      player.pause();
      players.add(player);
    }
  }

I also tried to load them asynchronously. "###### All Loaded" was printed right after the program initialized. But the sound is not played when used.
  Future<void> _loadData() async{
    var futures = List.generate(notes.length, (i) async {
      try {
        players[i].setSource(AssetSource(notes[i]));
      } catch (e) {
        print('Error loading ${notes[i]}: $e');
      }
    });

    await Future.wait(futures);
    print("####### All Loaded");
  }

Last, I tried to use 'then' to load them at the same time. It worked! But TimeoutException occured. Only '#########TimeoutException' was printed.
Future<void> _loadData() async {
      try {
        var futures = List.generate(notes.length, (i) {
          return players[i].setSource(AssetSource(notes[i])).then((_) {
            print("############# ${notes[i]} Loaded");
          });
        });

        await Future.wait(futures);
        print("############## All Loaded");
        await players[0].resume();
      } catch (e) {
        print('##############$e');
      }
    }

All my audio files are in 'assets' e.g. assets/A4.ogg
pubspec.yaml
flutter:
  assets:
  - assets/G4.ogg
  - assets/G#4.ogg
  - assets/A4.ogg
  - assets/A#4.ogg


You could also show the line of code where you are calling _loadData().
